# Docker ASP.NET CORE 2.1 app in Visual Studio 2017. App does not start in debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I've been developing web app ASP.NET CORE 2.1 and running it in Visual Studio with Docker happily. Until now.

> Out of blue when I try to start debugging it does the build part, but
>   completely skips the running part. So now I am unable to debug my
>   Docker container with Visual Studio 2017.

There are no errors shown, everything is seems to be alright, except the fact, that app does not start. Debug output even not in the list of available ones in "Output"  tab.
Container seems to be running, but for some reason Visual Studio is not attaching to the Docker image for debugging.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Restarting Visual Studio or computer, deleting bin, obj,.vs, %userprofile%\vsdbg and %userprofile%\onecoremsvsmon didn't make any difference.
Here is my environment:

1. Windows10
2. Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.9.4
3. VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.4+28307.222
4. ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   15.8.31590
5. Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1
6. Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0

Docker:

1. Version 2.0.0.0-win81 (29211)
2. Build: 4271b9e
3. Engine:18.09.0
4. Compose:1.23.2
5. Machine:0.16.0

Container appears to be running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                 NAMES
22852e61b41a        dockertest          "tail -f /dev/null"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:50659->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:44304->443/tcp                         priceless_pare
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Dockertest/Dockertest.csproj", "Dockertest/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Dockertest/Dockertest.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Dockertest"
RUN dotnet build "Dockertest.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Dockertest.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Dockertest.dll"]
```

VS build output:

```
Target ContainerPrepareForLaunch:
  Using "ResolveVsDbgPath" task from assembly "C:\Users\aaaa\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.0.2105168\build\..\tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Tasks.dll".
  Task "ResolveVsDbgPath"
  Done executing task "ResolveVsDbgPath".
  Task "ContainerError" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETCoreApp' And
                                 '@(_Dockerfile->AnyHaveMetadataValue('TargetOS', 'Linux'))' == 'true' And
                                 !Exists('$(ContainerVsDbgPath)\vsdbg')) was evaluated as ('.NETCoreApp' == '.NETCoreApp' And
                                 'true' == 'true' And
                                 !Exists('C:\Users\aaaa\vsdbg\vs2017u5\vsdbg')).
  Using "ResolveMsVsMonPath" task from assembly "C:\Users\aaaa\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.0.2105168\build\..\tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Tasks.dll".
  Task "ResolveMsVsMonPath"
  Done executing task "ResolveMsVsMonPath".
  Using "PrepareForLaunch" task from assembly "C:\Users\aaaa\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.0.2105168\build\..\tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Tasks.dll".
  Task "PrepareForLaunch"
    docker build -f "C:\Projects\Dockertest\Dockerfile" -t dockertest  --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" "C:\Projects"
    Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.007GB

    Step 1/18 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
     ---> 1fe6774e5e9e
    Step 2/18 : WORKDIR /app
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 930ee0770e2d
    Step 3/18 : EXPOSE 80
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 4f184a8a4bd4
    Step 4/18 : EXPOSE 443
     ---> Using cache
     ---> bdf7dc4e92fd
    Step 5/18 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
     ---> 04868b49e01f
    Step 6/18 : WORKDIR /src
     ---> Using cache
     ---> c27b25a30aeb
    Step 7/18 : COPY ["Dockertest/Dockertest.csproj", "Dockertest/"]
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 009cbf61e5ae
    Step 8/18 : RUN dotnet restore "Dockertest/Dockertest.csproj"
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 9baf38b818c8
    Step 9/18 : COPY . .
     ---> ae210461c587
    Step 10/18 : WORKDIR "/src/Dockertest"
     ---> Running in 024c6719cbd3
    Removing intermediate container 024c6719cbd3
     ---> f398384b2049
    Step 11/18 : RUN dotnet build "Dockertest.csproj" -c Release -o /app
     ---> Running in cacc4471c224
    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

      Restore completed in 57.06 ms for /src/Dockertest/Dockertest.csproj.
      Dockertest -> /app/Dockertest.dll
      Dockertest -> /app/Dockertest.Views.dll
    Build succeeded.
        0 Warning(s)
        0 Error(s)

    Time Elapsed 00:00:09.30
    Removing intermediate container cacc4471c224
     ---> 5854863d47c7
    Step 12/18 : FROM build AS publish
     ---> 5854863d47c7
    Step 13/18 : RUN dotnet publish "Dockertest.csproj" -c Release -o /app
     ---> Running in 69df3a178cd7
    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

      Restore completed in 67.48 ms for /src/Dockertest/Dockertest.csproj.
      Dockertest -> /src/Dockertest/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/Dockertest.dll
      Dockertest -> /src/Dockertest/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/Dockertest.Views.dll
      Dockertest -> /app/
    Removing intermediate container 69df3a178cd7
    Step 14/18 : FROM base AS final
     ---> 766815671751
     ---> bdf7dc4e92fd
    Step 15/18 : WORKDIR /app
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 61f28b8a64fa
    Step 16/18 : COPY --from=publish /app .
     ---> 6b6711105d65
    Step 17/18 : ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Dockertest.dll"]
     ---> Running in f3be0a8361ee
    Removing intermediate container f3be0a8361ee
     ---> 774100a76bc9
    Step 18/18 : LABEL com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio
     ---> Running in 76d649057957
    Removing intermediate container 76d649057957
     ---> dbf49735c067
    Successfully built dbf49735c067
    Successfully tagged dockertest:latest
    SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
    docker rm -f ce37c3274e9a73fdfeb0b5cb48d451cf3fea687ee3b5c91388ecad1d1f695149
    ce37c3274e9a73fdfeb0b5cb48d451cf3fea687ee3b5c91388ecad1d1f695149
    docker run -dt -v "C:\Users\aaaa\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw" -v "C:\Users\aaaa\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro" -v "C:\Users\aaaa\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro" -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80" -e "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44304" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -p 50659:80 -p 44304:443 --entrypoint tail dockertest -f /dev/null
    22852e61b41ad164632588db2b4027ad59cc5e876956fb99c7e8eadcbcfcdd77
  Done executing task "PrepareForLaunch".
Target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" skipped. Previously built successfully.
Target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" skipped. Previously built successfully.
Target ReportTypeScriptVersion:
  Using "FormatLocalizedString" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\3.1\build\TypeScript.Tasks.dll".
  Task "FormatLocalizedString"
  Done executing task "FormatLocalizedString".
  Task "FormatLocalizedString" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(TypeScriptVersionCheckResult)' == 'Downgrade' OR '$(TypeScriptVersionCheckResult)' == 'Upgrade') was evaluated as ('NoneSpecified' == 'Downgrade' OR 'NoneSpecified' == 'Upgrade').
  Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(TypeScriptShowVersionWarning)' == 'true' AND '$(TypeScriptVersionCheckResult)' == 'NoneSpecified') was evaluated as ('' == 'true' AND 'NoneSpecified' == 'NoneSpecified').
  Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(TypeScriptShowVersionWarning)' == 'true' AND ('$(TypeScriptVersionCheckResult)' == 'Downgrade' OR '$(TypeScriptVersionCheckResult)' == 'Upgrade')) was evaluated as ('' == 'true' AND ('NoneSpecified' == 'Downgrade' OR 'NoneSpecified' == 'Upgrade')).
  Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(TypeScriptBuildMode)' == 'true' AND ($(TypeScriptToolsVersion.StartsWith('2.')) OR $(TypeScriptToolsVersion.StartsWith('1.')))) was evaluated as ('' == 'true' AND (False OR False)).
Target Build:
Target CleanupEmptyRefsFolder:
  Using "RemoveDir" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
  Task "RemoveDir"
    Directory "C:\Projects\Dockertest\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\refs" doesn't exist. Skipping.
  Done executing task "RemoveDir".
Target "ExecuteToolsTarget" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(ToolsTarget)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
Target "_PackAsBuildAfterTarget" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(GeneratePackageOnBuild)' == 'true' AND '$(IsInnerBuild)' != 'true') was evaluated as ('false' == 'true' AND '' != 'true').
Target "DotNetPublish" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(DeployOnBuild)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).

Done building project "Dockertest.csproj".

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:04:53.13
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**EDIT:**
Noticed, that VS "seats" "too long" on following task(before that step has been faster):

```
docker build -f "C:\Projects\Dockertest\Dockerfile" -t dockertest  --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" "C:\Projects"
```

Comment: What's the output of the Debug window?

Comment: @vzwick  Nothing. That option not even avaliable in "Show output from" combbox at Output tab.

Comment: Anything in the output from `docker logs <container>`?

Comment: @ESG Nothing. Nothing at all.

Comment: Dumb question, but: is the docker-compose project selected as the startup project?

Comment: @vzwick Yes, It is. But I understand reason why are you asking.:))) Thanks man for the interest to my sorrow, but I've found the remedy. I've posted my solution, so if u are curious check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, everything is working now! I am jumping up and down on a pile of pulled hairs, not because I am completely hairless now, but because I've fixed it!:)))

Without further ado, here is what broke the ice:
for some reason Docker For Windows lost "connection"(for lack of the better word or permissions, maybe?) to the drive where project has been residing on. This is exactly what I did to remedy the situation:

1. Open Docker For Window "Settings" menu
2. Went to "Shared Drives"
3. Unchecked "Shared" check box(mark already been there) for the drive, where project resides
4. Clicked "Apply" button
5. Checked "Shared" check box again and clicked "Apply" button again.

During last step login box popped up twice, telling me, that Docker need my credentials to access the drive. Domain name has been prepopulated with my login name. I've entered my password and clicked "OK" button on both occasions.Then I started project and, voila, login page of my web app showed in the browser as expected. Simple, yet so devious!:))

To be totally honest while I've been busy pulling my hairs out, I also did clean up my drive to free some space. I've released to the Wild about 10 GB. IDK, if that contributed or not to the success, but I've read, that some people did that too and it was beneficial for the Docker.

Comment: I experienced the same problem with Visual Studio 2019 and Core 3.0 project. Just  rechecked shared drives and voila! It works. One may be important moment: I gave a shared access to Docker where the VS project reside.